# Do the high / low levels of an I²C slave's response have to be of identical voltage as the levels of the I²C master's message?

Tags: i2c

I've got an IC (a [TDA7318](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/cd00000150.pdf)) with an operating voltage of +9 V. It's gonna be controlled by a Raspberry Pi 3B (output signal voltage: V_high = 3.3 V). Now I'd like to make sure that the responses sent by the TDA to the Pi do not exceed 3.3 V, as otherwise it might get fried.

So here is the "general" version of my question: When the master sends signals at V_high = 3.3 V into the I²C bus, does the I²C spec require all slaves to send their responses to the master at the same V_high level?

In this special case, my question reads as follows: Will my IC use a V_high = 3.3 V for the responses it sends into the I²C bus even if its V_cc is 9 V? Or should I rather use a level shifter for safety?

Comment: What does the datasheet say how the I2C bus works?

Comment: Do you mean the TDA's datasheet? It's specified on p. 8, but I can't find any information on the output hi / lo levels. Only the "Output Voltage SDA Acknowledge" of 0.4 V is mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I2C bus levels for the TDA7318 are on page 5 of the datasheet.

It accepts 3V as the minimum logic high voltage.

And besides the I2C bus is open-drain, so it is not the chips that determine the bus high voltage, it is the pull-up resistors that set the voltage, and on the Raspberry Pi the resistors are to 3.3V. There won't be 9V on the bus.

Comment: Yes, thx. I've already read about the min. bus high level of 3 V. They shouldn't pose an issue to the Pi.